# Round Corner (css and javascript)

Tags: css, rounded-corners

Please go to: http://jlecologia.com/page1c.html to see the problem

The top box look fine but in IE6 there is a **double** **top** and **bottom** border.

can somebody point me ut what i have done wrong ?

Or can anybody tell me a javascript rounded box that accept to do that effect with the border that is unequal. I have test some and they all fail, so i have done the picture round box but i like the jQuery javascript approach better.

Comment: posting some code might help with the request

Comment: see the link... a demo is better that any copy/paste code

Comment: Setting the line-height and font-size to zero didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for background images to to have them repeat.

Try: background: transparent url(../images/roundbox-top.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;

---

*Edited after comment to provide full solution:*

IE6 sets the height of empty divs to your font-size if the height specified in the css is less than the font-size.

On #roundbox .top and #roundbox .bottom, put

```
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
```

That will collapse the div to the right height.

Comment: that do the trick for the bottom, but not for the top (see the fixed file at the same address)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the JQuery's [round corner plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners)
And [here](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html) is a demo

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the change you've made for the bottom border, setting the font-size of the element with class "top" to 7px fixes it in my IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the web developer toolbar in Firefox to validate the CSS and HTML. I did a quick check and there are multiple errors in each. The rendering difference, I suspect, is because IE does not handle malformed content as well as FF. In particular, even small errors in CSS files tend to snowball in IE and melt down an otherwise good layout. Not sure if IE7 and IE8 have made any improvements in this regard.